# Android: How to add a layer on top no matter how many activities started?

Tags: java, android, layer

I want to play a gif animation and this view will move on the screen every second, but if I start an activity I need to add this view again and the position will change.

See the attached image below. I need to stick this over every view. Any way to do it?

[image]

Comment: can you post some java code or image what you actually want to do

Comment: Have you tried using Android built-in animation?

Comment: I am able to play gif. But I need this gif view always stick on top in Z direction.

Comment: Do you refer to navigation drawer? like this link ? [Navigation Bar](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/--Jem6sRRCs8/VJ5uAHTaHLI/AAAAAAAAAtE/6GM3fmnMjc4/s1600/933fee8cf6a8f48dfc1aa971bd2cc2b0.gif)

Comment: No. I need a gif always appear even I start an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one BaseActivity for all activities in your app to show Overlay View or Layout.
you can inherit BaseActivity on other Activity

You can add gif supported views or layouts 
for example i added overlay_layout in my showOverlay method.
you can call showOverlay method where ever you want to show and you can remove with removeOverlay with conditions.
Please note that showOverlay and removeOverlay should be in BaseActivity

```
void showOverlay(){
LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay_layout, null);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION;
final WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager);
activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mWindowManager.addView(layout, params);
}
void removeOverlay(){
windowManager.removeView(view);
}
```

Comment: I have already found a method to achieve this. It is quick similar to your answer but it is using Service. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

set this view into **WindowManager** and it will always show on top

Comment: could you explain more?